# how to do a post listing with tag filter with symfony2

Tags: symfony, many-to-many, doctrine-query

I have this very usual question. but I spent a lot of time cannot solve. I am using symfony2 with doctrine. any help? appreciate

let say I have 3 entities: **Post, Tag, PostTag**

- **Post** has many **Tags**
- **Tag** has many **Posts**

I need to do a **Post** listing filter by **Tag**.

```
SELECT p,pt FROM PostTag pt LEFT JOIN pt.post p
```

this result duplicated posts due to a **Post** has many **PostTags**.

any solution please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p FROM Post p JOIN p.postTags pt JOIN pt.tag t WHERE t.name = :name
```

Don't forget to make sure `Post` has one-to-many with `PostTag`.